# Web Push Notification - Got notification but no pop up

Tags: javascript, web-push

I followed Google's "Adding Push Notification to a Web App" tutorial.  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications

I was able to receive notifications and console did print the messages but there was no pop up alert. I tried it on both Edge and Chrome and have reset settings on both browsers to allow notification and pop up.

I am testing this at home too so there has no corporate firewall issue.

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of running around, I finally find the root cause. I forgot to enable notification on the OS. So the code on the link worked fine.